# How to move namespace declaration from operation to root element?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

our soap message looks like the following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
   <...>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:operation xmlns="urn:namespace2" xmlns:ns2="urn:namespace1">
        <rootElement>
            <childElement>
                 <....>
            </childElement>
        </rootElement>
    </ns2:operation>
</soap:Body>
```

But I need the following output:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
 <...>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:operation  xmlns:ns2="urn:namespace1">
        <rootElement xmlns="urn:namespace2">
            <childElement>
               <..>
            </childElement>
        </rootElement>
    </ns2:operation>
</soap:Body>
```

I've used the wsdl2java from cxf to generate the webservice/jaxb classes.
Is it possible to change the behaviour of jaxb so that the namespace is declared in the root elment and not in the operation defined in the wsdl?

I think one possibility is to use a CxfOutInterceptor to manipulate the message before sending, but I think there have to be a more easier/faster solution.(like, for example,  adding a simple annotation that I don't know to the generated jaxb classes).

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: Why do you need the second format?

Comment: Both variants are valid I know, but it seems like the system of our customer can't handle this. I'm not rly sure how they get the content of the message, it looks like they are just cutting out the message
        <rootElement>
            <childElement>
                 <....>
            </childElement>
        </rootElement>

They don't pay attention that the namespace is declared 1 element above in the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in my project was combining the [CXF XSLT Interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/xslt-feature.html) with a stylesheet modeled after https://stackoverflow.com/a/16366984/5971497

In your case, you would use ns2:operation instead of Accounts, but don't forget to add a xmlns:ns2 to the stylesheet element.

In my case the client system was too dumb to copy the xmlns definitions from the parent to the child element while extracting the child element from the response.

Here's my stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <!-- copy any unmatched nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- match any element with the wst prefix -->
  <xsl:template match="wst:*">
    <!-- create a new element with the same name as the matched one -->
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
      <!-- copy the xmlns attributes except for saml2 and ds, so they are declared on the Assertion element -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="./namespace::*[string(.)!='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion' and string(.)!='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. It's not really what I was looking for, I thought there would be an easier way but it's fine :).